# Nuxt 3 rich JSON payload serialisation

Tags: serialization, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

The Nuxt team introduced support for sending class instances from the server to the client in [Nuxt 3.4.0](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20208) as an experimental feature & made it enabled by default in [Nuxt 3.5.0](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20879)

However, in my opinion, the documentation has been quite falling behind... As someone who hasn't had much experience with custom serializers, I am not so sure how to implement my own based on the example they provided in the release notes:

```js
// example of a custom payload plugin from the Nuxt team
export default definePayloadPlugin(() => {
  definePayloadReducer('BlinkingText', data => data === '<original-blink>' && '_')
  definePayloadReviver('BlinkingText', () => '<revivified-blink>')
})
```

I have so many questions like:

- Are all of the payload plugins run every time a payload is sent from the server to the client and does only the one that returns a truthy value in the payloadReducer callback get used on the specific type?
- Does the name of the payloadReducer and the payloadReviver matter? Is it tied to something? Or can it be anything as long as the reviver & reducer have the same name?
- Will the reviver automatically run on the client during hydration?

### My solution

After some experimentation, I came up with this plugin for my `ApiResponse` class:

```js
export default definePayloadPlugin(() => {
    definePayloadReducer('ApiResponse', data => data instanceof ApiResponse && data.getReducedData())
    definePayloadReviver('ApiResponse', data => new ApiResponse(...data))
})
```

I defined a method in the class, which returns the constructor parameters in an array:

```js
getReducedData() {
    return [this.data, this.model, this.responseMeta]
}
```

And I am using the following `transform` method in my `useFetch` wrapper:

```js
transform: (data) => new ApiResponse(data, this.model, responseMeta),
```

This, however, results in the following error: `500 Cannot stringify a function`

```
at flatten (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:102:15)
at flatten (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:60:39)
at flatten (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:166:43)
at flatten (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:166:43)
at flatten (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:60:39)
at stringify (./node_modules/devalue/src/stringify.js:178:16)
at renderPayloadJsonScript (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:12654:32)
at ./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:12578:29
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

If I do the transform in the following way, it *kinda* works:

```js
// in useFetch options:
transform: this.transformResponse


// the transformResponse function:
transformResponse(response, responseMeta = null) {
    return new ApiResponse(response, this.model, responseMeta)
}
```

The `data` returned from `useFetch` **is** indeed `instanceof ApiResponse` on the client in this case, however, the `this` context in the callback is different so I have no way to access the model & as there is no way for me to pass the `responseMeta` into the constructor.
I don't understand why the payloadPlugin seems to work in this second example and not in the first one... There is no mention of the `definePayloadPlugin`, `definePayloadReducer` & `definePayloadReviver` functions in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Let's go through the points one by one:

> Are all of the payload plugins run every time a payload is sent from the server to the client and does only the one that returns a truthy value in the payloadReducer callback get used on the specific type?

Yes.

> Does the name of the payloadReducer and the payloadReviver matter? Is it tied to something? Or can it be anything as long as the reviver & reducer have the same name?

As far as I'm aware, the name has nothing to do with the type - so it can be anything as long as the reducer & the reviver match.

> Will the reviver automatically run on the client during hydration?

Yes.

Basically, I'm pretty sure that every payload plugin runs for every payload on the client during hydration.

---

Now let's discuss why my first solution didn't work:

In the `ApiResponse` class, I instantiate a new `ApiModel` subclass based on the model reference provided in the constructor. **THIS** `ApiModel` reference is the "function that could not be stringified".

The version where I only provided a reference to the **response transform function** (`transform: this.transformResponse`) worked because `this.model` was `undefined` in that context.

So it appears I can't pass classes in any form, whether they're instantiated or not... which does make sense, I suppose...

---

### How did I solve it?

In the `getReducedData` method, instead of passing the model reference, I return the model's name as a string.

```js
getReducedData() {
    return [this.data, createModelKey(this.model), this.responseMeta]
}
```

I then use that name in a map to instantiate the appropriate model on the client in the reviver, like this:

```js
const classes = {
    [createModelKey(ProductModel)]: ProductModel,
}

export default definePayloadPlugin(() => {
    definePayloadReducer('ApiResponse', data => data instanceof ApiResponse && data.getReducedData())
    definePayloadReviver('ApiResponse', (data) => {
        const model = data[1] ? classes[data[1]] : null
        return new ApiResponse(data[0], model, data[2])
    })
})
```

Please let me know if there's anything I'm doing wrong or if there are better ways to approach this. 
If possible, I would prefer not to add the model classes to the map manually...

I hope this helps someone!